# Power Query Combine Binaries messes up data

Tags: powerquery

I'm combining a number of files from folder in Power Query 2013. For some reason, it adds the names of the first 2 columns to some random rows in the last two columns, or even replaces data with other column name.

[image: this is what happens]

First, I thought it's due to difference in column schemas (some files didn't have the last column). I aligned all files, but the issue didn't go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround by ensuring the CSV files have no blank cells in them. This removed most of errors.

Still, sometimes it adds the first column's name to the last cell of each file, but that can be fixed by replace value.

Answer (score 1):

Combining binaries in Excel can cause formatting problems. To understand the problem, you'd probably need to share your files (you could remove any sensitive data, but include enough columns to reproduce the problem).

---

Alternatively, if you use Power BI Desktop there's a [new feature for combining binary files in a safer way](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-combine-binaries/).

Comment: I don't have the Power BI desktop yet... How could I share the files with you? I don't think my status here allows me to.

Comment: You could share the files by uploading to OneDrive or Dropbox, then send the link to carlwa @ microsoft.com  Make sure to include the Excel workbook too :)

Comment: Carl, i'll send you files later today - thanks a lot!!

Comment: marking this as answer, as if i had desktop power bi, this would solve the issue.